# Windows Dialog : how to convert type PWSTR to char*?

Tags: c++, windows, casting, wchar-t

I am using a Windows Dialog to select a file. The output type I receive is a `PWSTR`. Whenever I've tried to convert it to `char*`, all I get is the first character of the string (ie `'C'`).

For some context, my variable name is `pszFilePath`. I have used multiple casting types, like using `reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast`, and `(char*)pszFilePath`. All of which either do not work, or cause an error.

Comment: On Windows a wide character is commonly two bytes, and the characters are stored in UTF-16 encoding. A simple cast will not convert each character from something that can be displayed as narrow characters. Generally, if you ever feel the need to do a C-style cast (like `(char *) ...`) then you should take it as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. There are functions that can convert wide-character strings into their corresponding narrow character representation. But generally, don't mix wide and narrow character functions. Use one or the other, *always*.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte

Comment: Chances are high you do **not** want to actually perform this conversion, but work with the string in its original, wide character format. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcstombs-wcstombs-l.

Comment: Have a look at this C++ (non-windows API version) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs. But know conversion can do all kind of stuff dependent on locale settings. (only kind of works reproducibly on what in the end will be `ASCII` characters)

Comment: Depending on which dialog API you are actually using, there may be an ANSI version available that outputs `char` strings instead of `wchar_t` strings.

Answer (score 0):

PWSTR is a wchar_t* string

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings

So you need to convert wchar_t* to char*. wcstombs(mbstring,wcstring,N) from stdlib.h does exactly that.

About converting only first character of your string, I guess you use something like sizeof(var) / sizeof(PWSTR) to allocate memory for your char* string but it doesn't work this way. I don't really know how to get the length of PWSTR since strlen() doesn't work with wchar_t*, so you need some struct that will count it or anything else.

Example

```
PWSTR pw = new wchar_t;
PCWSTR pcw = L"qwe\n\0";
wcscpy(pw, pcw);
char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
wcstombs(c, pw, 5);
printf("%s", c);
```

Comment: The [`wcslen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcslen) function is the standard equivalent of `strlen` for `wchar_t` strings.